# Entity implements Parcelable

Tags: android, parcelable, objectbox-android

I'm a Android Coder,The version of ObjectBox I was using was 3.1.2, and I couldn't make the entity class implement the Parcelable interface. If I did, I would get an error at run time ==> [class not def exception]

I want Entity Class in OB can support Parcelable compiler and run

Comment: Please edit your question. Add the code that you wrote for your entity class and also the exception/log message with stacktrace from logcat when you got the runtime exception.

Comment: The problem has been resolved because it was bytecode editing that caused the virtual machine to load check errors, not ObjectBox. but thanks

Comment: Glad you were able to solve the problem. Please create an answer that describes how you solved it and accept that answer. It might help someone else with a similar issue and it will get this question off the list of unanswered questions.